# Update the attributes/fields that have been changed PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am building the profile section of a php site. It offers a profile edit section. Say, I have the details user_id, user_name, user_firstname, user_lastname,user_email in my $_SESSION variable.

So, if any user edits any of these attributes, by going to localhost/profile/edit,
how should I go on about updating the database columns that have been changed?

ie 1. Should I compare the post data with my session variable and update only the changed fields? But I don't know how to implement this.

2. Should I update all fields?
3. SOme other standard way of doing things?

If you need more clarification, let me know.

Comment: @Federico Can you please elaborate. How can I use object relational mapping with this?

Comment: You don't do such things "by hand", but typically use or implement something like a ORM, an object relational mapper which takes an object (with all its properties) and turns it into an array that can be stored inside a table row. Inside that ORM you implement creation and update actions. If the update action overwrites all or just the changed columns is not really important then any more, especially to the outside world.

Comment: @arkascha: Hey. Can you give me a link to get started with it?

Comment: Just read about "ORM" in wikipedia and then google for "php orm".

Comment: As from my point of view, there is no need to compare posted data with the session, you can update all the fields in single query...

Answer (score 3):

Between update all fields and just on field it's up to you. In a REST perspective you should use a PUT to update the whole resource and a PATCH to update just one field of the resource. So i think is really up to you!

In any case the flow should be:

- update the tables (one field or many)
- update session